# Starting Tomcat(Manager App) from terminal

Tags: apache, terminal, osx-lion, tomcat7

```
Last login: Fri Oct 14 02:32:10 on ttys000
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ cd ..
➜  /Users  cd ..
➜  /  cd ..
➜  /  cd Developer 
➜  /Developer  cd usr 
➜  usr  cd local 
➜  local  cd apache-tomcat-7.0.22 
➜  apache-tomcat-7.0.22  cd bin 
➜  bin  sudo chown -R Vinisa /Developer/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin
Password:
➜  bin  sudo chmod +x /Developer/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/*.sh
➜  bin  sh startup
sh: startup: No such file or directory
➜  bin  sh startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Developer/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Developer/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Developer/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Developer/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Developer/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
➜  bin
```

The above steps are for starting the Tomcat(Manager App) on Mac 10.7. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am getting the following error - [401 Unauthorized error while logging in Manager-App of Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763560/401-unauthorized-error-while-logging-in-manager-app-of-tomcat).

Thanks!

Comment: It worked after `sh shutdown.sh` and then `sh startup.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after sh shutdown.sh and then sh startup.sh